# Resolve chroot problems with php5-fpm

Tags: apache, variables, path, php, chroot

I am using Apache (and can't switch to nginx or lighttpd because of the customers), and as many others, I have problems with the following variables:

```
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]
$_SERVER["PATH_TRANSLATED"]
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]
```

Because of the chroot, the variables passed by apache's mod_fastcgi to php5-fpm are screwed up and so don't match with the proper ones.
Let me show you an example:

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = /home/vhosts/h0001/home/domains/test.com
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] = /home/vhosts/h0001/php-fpm
$_SERVER["PATH_TRANSLATED"] = /home/vhosts/h0001/home/domains/test.com/phpinfo.php
```

Instead of:

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = /home/domains/test.com
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] = /php-fpm
$_SERVER["PATH_TRANSLATED"] = /home/domains/test.com/phpinfo.php
```

So, it seems easy to do, since all I need is to remove the "/home/vhosts/hXXXX" from those variables.

I've thought of using the auto_prepend_file directive inside php.ini and add something like this:

```
<?php
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace('/home/vhosts/h0001','',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])
    $_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'] = str_replace('/home/vhosts/h0001','',$_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'])
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = str_replace('/home/vhosts/h0001','',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])
```

This would allow the right variables to be set, however I have two problems about it:

- I can't prepend any file since php doesn't work at all ("No input file.") because it looks in the wrong directory for scripts
- Setting an alias in the virtualhost doesn't seem to work because the chroot environment takes place on /home/vhosts/hXXXX and the various domain docroots are into /home/vhosts/hXXXX/home/domains/domain.tld/; and even with the alias, Apache is still giving away the wrong paths.

I've seen a lot of people dealing with it with nginx, solving the problem (allows editing the SCRIPT_FILENAME and DOCUMENT_ROOT, Apache doesn't), and other people solving the issue symlinking the appropriate directory tree *inside* the chroot to get around the problem. This last solution really sucks.

Another way to do it is using [this patch](http://orfika.net/src/mod_fastcgi-chroot-patch/), but even trying it, it seems something went wrong: trying to compile it with *apxs2 -cia mod_fastcgi.c*, throws an error about *undefined symbol: fcgi_config_new_static_server*, and I don't know how to fix this (compiling static? how to do it with apxs2?)

The best solution about it seems to be patching PHP by hand, but I'm not sure it would be the cleanest thing to do...!

Comment: If you can switch to mod_fcgid, I'll give you my simple patch that fixes this issue.

Comment: I'd like to see how did you fix it, even if I think I can't switch to mod_fcgid since I'm connecting to php5-fpm through a tcp connection and not a socket (I need this behaviour because of a clustered solution: the webserver doesn't need to be on the same machine the php is in)
Thank you in the meantime :P

Comment: @strkol I'm thinking about patching php-fpm: since here is where the chroot happens and the directive chroot = /path/ is located, probably this would be the one who has to be patched in order to work properly. Any other solution would still be interesting to hear! :)